# Clean Architecture - Injection of app services into another app services

Tags: dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture, decoupling, coupling

I'm working in a PHP API trying to follow a Clean Architecture pattern in order to be able to extract modules of the app to micro-services in the future.

My question is how application services should use each other without getting coupled.
Even if I'm injecting a bound abstract (interface), injected service's methods are handling entities outside the host service's domain. So in the future i would have coupled services and i will not be able to externalize them.

```php
<?php

/* Domain: INJECTED */
class InjectedService implements InjectedServiceInterface 
{
    public function get(int $id): InjectedServiceDomainEntity 
    {
        return $this->repo->findById($id);
    }
}

/* Domain: HOST */
class HostService implements HostServiceInterface 
{
    /** @var InjectedServiceInterface $injectedService */
    private $injectedService;

    public function __construct(InjectedServiceInterface $injectedService)
    {
        $this->injectedService = $injectedService;
    }

    public function someMethod($someId)
    {
        /** @var InjectedServiceDomainEntity $injectedServiceEntity */
        $injectedServiceEntity = $this->injectedService->get($someId);
        // here I'm managing an outsider entity
    }
}
```

at `someMethod` am i not coupling the services? managing an entity from another service/domain?
what happens when i want to move the `HostService` to a micro-service?

Thanks a lot in advance for your ideas.

Comment: Are you sure the 2 services are application services? I the code you provided the injected service can be a domain service or you can just inject the repo if you only need to get the entity

Comment: @MohamedBouallegue yes, `OrderService` and `PaymentService` respectively. One needs the other. Question is more like if this is the place for DTO's or if these are only to pass data between layers

Answer (score 1):

*Even though you are using PHP the following may provide useful on a conceptual level*:

Probably the simplest would be to implement some generic mediator that you depend on in your application layer (integration concern).

I have a simple open-source [implementation](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Core.Mediator) with another option being Jimmy Bogard's [mediatr](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR).

In my implementation a particular participant would depend on the relevant service(s) and act on the relevant message being passed.  Any given participant can respond to various messages.  In your case there may be two participants with each relying on the relevant service.

This mechanism also works well when trying to cut down on the number of dependencies injected into, or used by, a class.

In the past I have also used an application `Task` (not to be confused with .Net `Task`) that represents a use-case and then it would accept *both* `OrderService` as well as `PaymentService` (using your example here) and interact with the two in the relevant way.  The code dependency of one on the other could be extracted into meaningful methods.

The mediator is a more implicit implementation of this concept whereas some use-case specific class would be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

If I could correctly understand your question, there are two services for example, `OrderService` along with `PaymentService`. `OrderService` is needed the `PaymentService`.

**There are two scenarios**

**First scenario:**
`PaymentService` is third party for `OrderService`, which could be independently developed. If it's true, it's better to put `PaymentService` in **Infrastructure layer** and inject it in application layer services like `OrderService`.

**Second scenario:**
`PaymentService` isn't third party.
In terms of clean code, there is an issue in this case. Single Responsibility Principle would be violated. There is more than one reason to change methods like `someMethod`. Calling a method from another service inside another one makes more than one reason to change. It would be better to call `PaymentService` in presentation layer and fetch data needed for `OrderService` and after that `someMethod` in `OrderService` could be invoked by passing the data without any need to inject `PaymentService`.

Discussing this sort of questions is a bit hard. Hope to say my meaning properly. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will always have coupling if service X uses service Y, BUT:

Clean Architecture and mostly its dependency inversion principle gives you the tools necessary to make the coupling or depedency unidirectional.

In your case DI and interfaces allow you to have the `Host` module depend on the `Injected` module but never the other way round. You could even make the Host module depend on nothing if you move `InjectedServiceInterface` and an interface for `InjectedServiceDomainEntity` into the Host module. If you call `get` now you will only deal with source code from the Host module.

With DI those interfaces are implemented in a different module. With Microservices those interfaces are implemented by a remote calling infrastructure component.

There is no point in trying to reduces coupling to zero because then your modules do not interact at all. At least it appears that way in the source code

One more thought: in a dynamically types language like PHP you propbably do have the opportunity to have more decoupling if you want by using function types instead of declared interfaces as parameters and duck typing for entities/objects.